# Why when I log in the consule a variable that contains a setTimeOut method it equals a number?

Tags: javascript, methods, settimeout

```
const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
 console.log('After 5 seconds');
}, 5000);
console.log(timeoutID); // 1
```

Why when I print in the console a variable that contains a setTimeout method it equals a number?

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns the timer ID.

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I print in the console a variable that contains a setTimeout
> method it equals a number?

You print the `setTimeout`'s return value which is assigned to that variable and represents the timeout ID for later use

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
> the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
> passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that setTimeout() and setInterval()
> share the same pool of IDs, and that clearTimeout() and
> clearInterval() can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity,
> however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when
> maintaining your code.
>
> It is guaranteed that a timeout ID will never be reused by a
> subsequent call to setTimeout() or setInterval() on the same object (a
> window or a worker). However, different objects use separate pools of
> IDs.

Comment: Do you mean a handle?And if so,How the porgram chooses what number to call the timeout?